# Login screen Ubuntu. How to add to ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, login, login-screen

When I installed Ubuntu I didn't switch on login requirement. So when I'm connecting to Ubuntu using VNC I instantly see my desktop? 
Is it ok for my PC performance? There is installed apache server. Should there be a login screen whole the time so if I connect using vnc I should login. How can I add login screen?

Comment: VNC requires to have credentials to connect in the first place. I don't exactly know why having a lockscreen or not having a lockscreen would do anything to performance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to disable automatic login.

To do this, go to System Settings. Click on "User Accounts". Click the "unlock" button at the upper right corner of the window, then change "Automatic Login" to off.